# Как повернуть фигуру тетриса?

Tags: c#, геометрия

Есть фигура из тетриса (любая из 7), а в коде прописан массив из `Point`. Этот массив состоит из 4 элементов, так как в тетрисе каждая фигура — это 4 квадрата.

```
Point[] cord = new Point[4] { new Point(0,4), new Point(0,5), 
                              new Point(0,6), new Point(0,6) }
```

И есть игровое поле:

```
int[] field = new int[10, 20];
```

Оно заполнено нулями, кроме координат из cord (они заполнены единицами).

Так вот, как поворачивать эту фигуру на 90? Может есть какая-нибудь формула, а то прописывать в коде 4 положения каждой фигуры это не очень.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, как с помощью 4 точек вы определяете фигуру. Правильно ли я понял, что 4 точки - это центры квадратов, из которых состоит фигура?

Comment: Очень даже очень. Я заводил двумерный массив 4х4, в котором указывал какие ячейки активные, а какие нет. Соответственно, "поворот" это тривиальная задача закрашивания нужных ячеек.

Comment: [Ассоциация](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42519/312041)

Comment: @AndreiKhotko 4 точки, это координаты квадратов в матрице из которых состоит фигура

Comment: @Log1c0 тогда если у вас работа с матрицей, а не с графическим холстом, то Alexander и tym предложили хорошие решения

Comment: Можете просто сделать массив состояний для каждой фигуры и переключаться между ними (если препятствия в игре не мешают). Это самый простой способ поворачивать фигурки тетриса, который я знаю.

Comment: @trollingchar Я написал об этом в вопросе, мне данный способ очень не нравится

Comment: @tym32167 Обновил вопрос, мне очень понравилось решение, но я не знаю как его реализовать с таким кодом, можете помочь?

Comment: у вас всегда только 4 точки?

Comment: @tym32167 Ну, у каждой фигуры четыре.

Comment: тогда зачем вообще городить алгоритм, можно же так руками перемешать?

Comment: @tym32167 Я понимаю, но все же хочу алгоритмом, это легче. Просто если я захочу добавить новые фигуры, предется опять все это делать, а так универсальное решение

Comment: Я бы хранил фигуру как координаты базовой точки плюс 4 точки смещений от неё. Тогда с поворотом не должно быть проблем. Ну почти не должно. Нужен костыль для поворота около границы поля. UPDATE: Нет, зря я это предложил - квадрат будет по-дурацки вращаться.

Comment: @Qwertiy Когда фигура поворачивается на 180 градусов, точки нужны другие

Comment: умножь данные точки на матрицу поворота. в чем проблема?

Comment: @Санаев Я уже решил проблему и написал ответ, дело в том что я не хочу для каждой фигуры создавать новую матрицу, я хочу универсальное решение для любой фигуры с любым размером и т.д

Comment: Не понял вас . Вы же умножает координаты на матрицу вращения 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал по простой формуле, все заработало:

```
x2 = px + py - y1

y2 = x1 + py - px
```

Где `px` и `py` это координаты квадрата, вокруг которого крутятся все остальные, а `x1` и `y1` это текущие координаты.

Answer (score 1):

Если исходный массив [0 1 2 3] выглядит как

```
0 1
2 3
```

То его ротация будет выглядеть как

```
1 3
0 2
```

То есть массив превращается в [1 3 0 2]

Чтобы это сделать для 4 элементов, не надо ни цмклов, ничего, например

```
public void Rotate<T>(T[] input)
{
    T i00 = input[0];
    T i01 = input[1];
    T i10 = input[2];
    T i11 = input[3];

    input[0] = i01;
    input[1] = i11;
    input[2] = i00;
    input[3] = i10;
}
```

Проверка

[image: ...]

Для общего случая я позаимствовал и немного допилил реализацию [отсюда](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inplace-rotate-square-matrix-by-90-degrees/)

```
static void Rotate<T>(int width, T[] mat)
{   
    for (int x = 0; x < width / 2; x++)
    {       
        for (int y = x; y < width - x - 1; y++)
        {           
            T temp = mat[GetIndex(x, y, width)];            

            mat[GetIndex(x, y, width)] = 
                mat[GetIndex(y, width - 1 - x, width)];         

            mat[GetIndex(y, width - 1 - x, width)] = 
                mat[GetIndex(width - 1 - x, width - 1 - y, width)];         

            mat[GetIndex(width - 1 - x, width - 1 - y, width)] = 
                mat[GetIndex(width - 1 - y, x, width)];         

            mat[GetIndex(width - 1 - y, x, width)] = temp;
        }
    }
}
static int GetIndex(int i, int j, int width)
{
    return i*width+j;
}
```

Проверка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]